# Intersection of RDDs based on predicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have

```
val foo: RDD[T]
val bar: RDD[T]
val f: (T, T) => Boolean
```

Without calling `collect()`, how can I find the members of `foo` for which there exists a member of `bar` that causes `f` to be `true`?

Specifically, in my case, `T` is a 2D-line and `f` checks geometric intersections. I'm looking for all `foo` lines that cross any `bar` line.

Comment: How big is `bar`? Do you need it as an RDD?

Comment: Both are very large and need to be RDDs.

Answer (score 1):

```
val intersections = foo.cartesian(bar).filter{ case (a,b) =>f(a,b) }.map(_._1).unique()
```

But this will be very slow.

An alternative solution based on logic: set of "intersects at least one" = total_set - set of "intersects none". Transforming thus the problem into finding `foo` that do not intersect any `bar`. I am going to write this solution in pseudocode.

```
while condition
      select randomly one bar
      collect foo's that intersect bar in remaining_foos
      update remaining_foos by filtering on previously collected foo's
apply above solution looking for opposite relation
```

In the implementation condition can be a fixed number of steps and/or reducing the size of remaining_foos to an acceptable level.

Use broadcast too distribute collected foo's